# Какое подлежащее в первом предложении и сказуемое во втором в придаточных частях данных СПП?

Tags: спп, сказуемые, подлежащее

В придаточной части первого предложения подлежащее "ели" или "ели одни"? Во втором предложении придаточной части сказуемым является "было пусто, голо"? Это один член или два однородных сказуемых, каким образом изобразить это на схеме предложения?

1. На горах, под метелями, где лишь ели одни вечно зелены, сел орел в тень под елями.
2. Где некогда все было пусто, голо, теперь младая роща разрослась.

Answer (score 1):

1. ***На горах, под метелями, где лишь ели одни вечно зелены, сел орел в тень под елями.***

Слово "одни" имеет значение частицы (только ели). Вероятно, подлежащим будет всё сочетание: лишь ели одни.

2. ***Где некогда все было пусто, голо, (там) теперь младая роща разрослась.***

Схема: (Где…), [     ].   Союзное слово «где», указательное слово «там» пропущено.
В придаточном однородные сказуемые: все было пусто, голо. На схеме между графическими символами сказуемого (обычно две черты) надо поставить запятую.